# How can I make this smoke look the way it should

Tags: smoke-simulation

I'm new to modelling, and I got stuck with making an appropriate smoke for coffee. How can I make those wavy smokes like in this picture:

[image: mewow]

What I have right now:

[image]

Comment: To be fair, if I were to address the term "like it should", what you have is much closer to reality. The one in the reference image looks like a candle that's been blown out; No hot liquid would ever have a steam pattern that looks like that.

Comment: heh thanks, maybe I'm pushing myself a little too far

Comment: Don't sweat it. Your question is still valid (vis a vis "how do I get the result in this example"), I'm just saying that if you're going for realism, you pretty much nailed it. Unfortunately, I'm not an authority on smoke simulations, or I'd give you those instructions. I'll look into it after work.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate it.